# Javascript, How to return value from foreach function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a function that need to return a value from a array.

```
function getValue(key) : value

function getValue(key) {
        var result = null;
        $scope.config.forEach(function(element) {
            if(element.app_key == "search_result_limit")
            result = element.app_value;
            break;
        });
        return result;
    }
```

i am trying to get this value but found undefined.

Please help.

Comment: ES6 `find`. `return $scope.config.find(o => o.app_key === 'search_result_limit') || {};`

Comment: @Tushar the function looks like it's supposed to return `null` for a no-match, not an empty object (and also just the `.app_value`, not the whole object)

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a filter method:

```
 $scope.config.filter(function(element) {
            return element.app_key == "search_result_limit";
 });
```

considering that your `$scope.config` is an array of objects...

Comment: Be aware this will return an array, not a value from an array as per the OP's requirements.

Comment: ya.. I missed out that part!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Modern JS has [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function getValue(key) {
    var obj = $scope.config.find(function(e) {
        return e.app_key === key;
    });
    return obj ? obj.app_value : null;
}
```

or in ES6 syntax:

```
function getValue(key) {
    var obj = $scope.config.find(e => e.app_key === key);
    return obj ? obj.app_value : null;
}
```

If you don't have ES6, you're better off just using a plain `for` loop:

```
function getValue(key) {
    for (var a = $scope.config, i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        if (a[i].app_key === key) {
            return a[i].app_value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Modern JS also have arrow function which will make code consice, as in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699181/javascript-how-to-return-value-from-foreach-function#comment62873000_37699181)

Comment: @Tushar yes, if you're talking "bleeding edge" modern.

Comment: [`find` BS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) & [Arrow Function BS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) Close I'll say.

Comment: @Tushar I forgot that `.find` is also ES6 - I thought it was ES5 :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put two statement inside if statement in a block.
Use this code, this might work :-

```
function getValue(key) : value

function getValue(key) {
        for ( var a = $scope.config, i=0, n = a.length; i< n ; i++){
              if (a[i].app_key === key) {
                  return a[i].app_value;
              }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Also you cannot `break` from `forEach`. Iteration will continue.

Comment: @ste2425 have done some changes...please look into it

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
function getValue(key) {      
    var result= $scope.config.filter(function(item) {
       return item.app_key == key;          
    });
    return result.length>0?result[0].app_value:null;         
}
```